# Error Opening VB file on cobol program to process an XML File

Tags: xml, cobol, jcl

Long Story short, I need to process an XML File in a cobol Program, which i've been reading about I can perform using the XML PARSE utility from enterprise cobol 6.3.

I don't have much experience working with Variable Length files, but our best guess is that the input file could be of variable length. I have a sample file which i want to test, which has the following Info screen

```
    Data Set Name . . . . : TDES.XML.SPOT.TR                                 
                                                                         
General Data                           Current Allocation                
 Management class . . : **None**        Allocated blocks  . : 5          
 Storage class  . . . : **None**        Allocated extents . : 1          
  Volume serial . . . : ABCXYZ                                          
  Device type . . . . : 3390                                             
 Data class . . . . . : **None**                                         
  Organization  . . . : PS             Current Utilization               
  Record format . . . : VB              Used blocks . . . . : 1          
  Record length . . . : 10000           Used extents  . . . : 1          
  Block size  . . . . : 10004                                           
  1st extent blocks . : 5                                               
  Secondary blocks  . : 0              Dates                             
  Data set name type  :                 Creation date . . . : 2021/10/27 
                                        Referenced date . . : 2021/10/27 
                                        Expiration date . . : ***None*** 
  SMS Compressible  . : NO
```

This is an extract of the cobol code i have implemented for this task

```
          *****************************************************************
           IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                         
           PROGRAM-ID.  XXXXXXXX.                                           
           AUTHOR.  XXXXXXXX.                                                
                                                                            
          ******************************************************************
          *            E N V I R O N M E N T       D I V I S I O N         *
          ******************************************************************
           ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                            
          *                                                                 
           CONFIGURATION SECTION.                                           
          *                                                                 
           SPECIAL-NAMES.                                                   
               DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA.                                      
                                                                            
          ******************************************************************
          *    I N P U T - O U T P U T      S E C T I O N                  *
          ******************************************************************
           INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.                                            
          *                                                                 
           FILE-CONTROL.                                                    
          ****************************************************************  
                                                                            
    DESODH     SELECT FENTRADA                                              
    DESODH         ASSIGN TO FENTRADA                                       
    DESODH         ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL                               
    DESODH         ACCESS MODE  IS SEQUENTIAL                               
    DESODH         FILE STATUS  IS FS-FENTRADA-XML.                         
                                                                            
                                                                            
          ******************************************************************
          *    D A T A     D I V I S I O N                                 *
          ******************************************************************
           DATA DIVISION.                                                   
          ******************************************************************
          *    FILE SECTION                                                *
          ******************************************************************
          *                                                                 
           FILE SECTION.                                                    
          *                                                                 
                                         
    DESODH FD  FENTRADA                                                     
    DESODH     LABEL RECORDS STANDARD                                       
    DESODH     RECORD IS VARYING FROM 1 TO 10000 DEPENDING ON W-REC-LENGTH  
    DESODH     RECORDING MODE IS V                                          
    DESODH     BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS.                                    
    DESODH 01  REG-FENTRADA.                                                
             02 PIC X OCCURS 1 TO 10000 DEPENDING ON W-REC-LENGTH.    
          
            WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                         
           *                                                                 
           ******************************************************************
           * DEFINICIÓN DEL FICHERO DE ENTRADA                              *
           ******************************************************************
            01  REG-ENTRADA             PIC X(1300).                         
           *                                                                 
           ******************************************************************
           * DEFINICIÓN DE LOS FICHEROS DE SALIDA                           *
           ******************************************************************
                COPY FMIF1113.                                               
           *                                                                 
           ******************************************************************
           * DEFINICIÓN DE VARIABLES WORKING                                *
           ******************************************************************
            01  W-VARIABLES-AUXILIARES.                                      
                                                                             
           ** VARIABLES A CAMBIAR EN CADA PROGRAMA:                          
                05 W-CONT-CAMPOS               PIC 9(03)  VALUE 46.          
           ** VARIABLES A CAMBIAR EN CADA PROGRAMA:                          
                05 W-SITUACION                 PIC 9(04)  VALUE ZEROS.       
                                                                             
                05 W-MENSAJE                   PIC X(100) VALUE SPACES.      
                05 W-STATUS                    PIC X(02)  VALUE SPACES.      
    ...................
           ******************************************************************
           *             P R O C E D U R E   D I V I S I O N                *
           ******************************************************************
            PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                              
                 PERFORM 1000-INICIO                                         
                 PERFORM 4000-PROCESO-XML UNTIL SI-FIN-PROCESO-XML           
                 PERFORM 3000-FINAL                                          
                 STOP RUN.                                                   
           ******************************************************************
           *  1000-INICIO.                                                  *
           ******************************************************************
            1000-INICIO.                                                     
                MOVE  1000                         TO W-SITUACION.           
     DESODH     PERFORM 1060-ABRIR-FICHERO-XML                               
               .                                                 
    DESODH******************************************************************
    DESODH*  1060-ABRIR-FICHERO-XML                                        *
    DESODH******************************************************************
    DESODH 1060-ABRIR-FICHERO-XML.                                          
    DESODH                                                                  
    DESODH     MOVE  1060                         TO W-SITUACION.           
    DESODH     SET NO-ERROR-LECTURA            TO TRUE                      
    DESODH     SET NO-FIN-FENTRADA             TO TRUE                      
    DESODH     SET NO-TAG-ENCONTRADO           TO TRUE                      
    DESODH     SET NO-ENCONTRADO-IDENTIFICADOR TO TRUE                      
    DESODH     SET NO-VERSION-INFORMATION      TO TRUE                      
    DESODH     SET NO-ENCODING-DECLARATION     TO TRUE                      
    DESODH     OPEN INPUT FENTRADA                                          
    DESODH                                                                  
    DESODH     IF  FS-FENTRADA-XML NOT = 00                                 
    DESODH        DISPLAY 'ERROR AL ABRIR FICHERO XML. FS: ' FS-FENTRADA-XML
    DESODH        MOVE 'ERROR OPEN FENTRADA '      TO W-MENSAJE             
    DESODH        MOVE FS-FENTRADA-XML             TO W-STATUS              
    DESODH        PERFORM PR-FIN-ERROR-LOGICO                               
    DESODH     END-IF.                                                      
    DESODH                                                                  
    DESODH     PERFORM 8000-LEER-FENTRADA                                   
    
    DESODH******************************************************************
    DESODH* 8000-LEER-FENTRADA                                              
    DESODH******************************************************************
    DESODH 8000-LEER-FENTRADA.                                              
    DESODH     MOVE 8000                         TO W-SITUACION             
                                                                            
    DESODH     READ FENTRADA                                                
    DESODH       AT END SET SI-FIN-PROCESO-XML TO TRUE                      
                                                                            
    DESODH     IF FS-FENTRADA-XML                NOT = 0                    
    DESODH        DISPLAY 'ERROR EN EL READ XML. FS: ' FS-FENTRADA-XML      
    DESODH        MOVE 'ERROR READ FENTRADA '          TO W-MENSAJE         
    DESODH        MOVE FS-FENTRADA-XML                 TO W-STATUS          
    DESODH        PERFORM PR-FIN-ERROR-LOGICO                               
    DESODH     END-IF                                                       
    DESODH     .     
...........................more code
```

And this is the error I'm getting while opening the file. File status 39. A mismatch on lengths that I'm not sure where it is.

```
        ********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************OF DATA **********************************
         IGZ0201W A file attribute mismatch was detected. File FENTRADA in program MIFD1113 had a record length of 10004 and      
                  the file specified in the ASSIGN clause had a record length of 10000.                                           
         ERROR AL ABRIR FICHERO XML. FS: 39                                                                                       
         ************************************************                                                                         
         *    PROGRAMA MIFD1113 ERROR EJECUCION         *                                                                         
         ************************************************                                                                         
         *  PARRAFO       : 1060                                                                                                  
         *  STATUS        : 39                                                                                                    
         *  NOMBRE RUT    :                                                                                                       
         *  MENSAJE       : ERROR OPEN FENTRADA                                                                                   
         *  CLAVE-ACCESO  :                                                                                                       
         ************************************************                                                                         
         CEE3250C The system or user abend U1777 R=NULL     was issued.                                                           
                  From compile unit BKCANCEL at entry point BKCANCEL at compile unit offset +000006D6 at entry offset +000006D6   
                   at address 000C30D6.                                                                                           
         <> LEAID ENTERED (LEVEL 02/26/2016 AT 17.55)                                                                             
         <> LEAID PROCESSING COMPLETE. RC=4                                                                                       
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************M OF DATA ********************************
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you want to process a `LINE SEQUENTIAL` file, but specified `ORGANIZATION SEQUENTIAL` an varying lengths, so you get a VB file that you actually don't want (with 4bytes padding for the length).

Change to `LINE SEQUENTIAL` and you're likely good.

More details can be seen in the [IBM Programmer's Guide "Processing line-sequential files"](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/4.2?topic=program-processing-line-sequential-files).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but that didn't fixed the issue. I'm getting now a File Status 90

Comment: You possibly want to share the complete setup including file association/JCL to allow people looking at this...

Comment: Thanks Simon. finally found a workaround.. The 4 control bytes from each VB record needs to be substracted from the File definittion, like this:
FD  FENTRADA                                                   
    LABEL RECORDS STANDARD                                     
    RECORD IS VARYING FROM 1 TO 9996 DEPENDING ON W-REC-LENGTH 
    RECORDING MODE IS V                                        
    BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS.                                  
01  REG-FENTRADA.                                              
  02 PIC X OCCURS 1 TO 9996 DEPENDING ON W-REC-LENGTH.